# C# Add two HTTPS bindings with two different certificate with the ServerManager not working

Tags: c#, iis, servermanager

I am trying to create two different bindings on two different site on IIS with C# from my website.
Those 2 binding needs to be set with a certificate (one specific for each bindings). The problem is, the bindings are correctly created but the two bindings are created with the same certificate.

Here my code :

```
public async Task AddBindings(string code)
{
    await AddBinding("Website1", "website1.com");
    await AddBinding("Website2", "website2.com");
}

private async Task AddBinding(string siteName, string urlDomain)
{
    using (ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager())
    {
        var site = serverMgr.Sites[siteName];

        var certif = GetCertificate("*." + urlDomain);
        site.Bindings.Add("*:443:" + urlDomain, certif.GetCertHash(), "My");

        serverMgr.CommitChanges();

        serverMgr.Dispose();
    }
}

private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string nameStartWith)
{
    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

    X509Certificate2 certif = null;

    foreach (var certificate in store.Certificates)
    {
        var certifDate = DateTime.Parse(certificate.GetEffectiveDateString());
        if (certificate.FriendlyName.StartsWith(nameStartWith))
        {
            certif = certificate;
        }
    }

    store.Close();

    return certif;
}
```

The "funny things" in the function AddBindings, in this order the two bindings are going to be created with the Website2 certificate, and if I change the order of the two rows it's going to use Website1.

Thank you very much for your helps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code definitely leads to that, because nowhere you specify that [SNI mappings should be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.sslflags?view=iis-dotnet#fields).

The correct function call you should make is this overloading version,

[Add (string bindingInformation, byte[] certificateHash, string certificateStoreName, Microsoft.Web.Administration.SslFlags sslFlags)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.bindingcollection.add?view=iis-dotnet#microsoft-web-administration-bindingcollection-add(system-string-system-byte()-system-string-microsoft-web-administration-sslflags))

You can read more about SNI mappings in Windows HTTP API from [here](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#ip-based-bindings).

Comment: Thank you, you were right I needed to make an SNI mappings ! I was not seeing the Add overload with SslFlags because I was in an older version of Microsoft.Web.Administration.

Comment: @ThibaultQ you will have to use the copy of `Microsoft.Web.Administration` from the machine itself, https://halfblood.pro/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know-b82f2c974da6